# How to force hibernate to flush and retrieve updated values?

Tags: hibernate

Using hibernate I am trying to retrieve values from database for update operation but i am not able to retrieve last inserted row..??

Answer (score 2):

To force Hibernate to flush, you can use session.flush() where session is the Hibernate Session object representing the currently opened session.

Answer (score 0):

Disable second level cache and use a new Session.

Comment: Both points are wrong. 2nd level cache (provided it's configured correctly) has nothing to do with this and using a new session (without closing / flushing an existing one) will do you no good.

Comment: If the OP tries to retrieve the last inserted record, kind of assumed the database manipulated it, hence the risk of second level cache interfering. If you use the old session, you will get the object from the session not from the database.